# Visual Studio 2008 Create Custom templates for Graph Theme and Fonts

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

Our company is requiring specific custom colors for report manager reports including, text boxes and all charts / graphs.  Can we create a custom graph template so each time we create a new graph, we use the template with our custom fonts as our base to start from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm, hard to do without having a default graph on every new report, that's customised in the item template.

The templates for new reports are stored ZIP files in the "Program Files" directory, under Microsoft Visual Studio *XX* -> Common*XX* -> IDE -> ItemTemplates -> Visual Basic/CSharp -> Reporting ->  e.g. 1033. A good start might be this article on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Alternatively you could provide a template to your developers that they would cut-and-paste from when developing new reports.

I think you'll still need to create a "style guide" as I don't believe there's a way to customise the toolbox when developers add a new textbox or graph.